# Customize colors in docx documents

Tags: java, ms-word, struts, openxml, docx

i have an docx file in application, when user selects colors(2 colors) in form and click generate i want to update the texts in docx with first color user selected and background with another color.

is this possible, if so how to achieve this. my project in struts2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org). The links below can be useful:

http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/change-font-and-font-size-t864.html
http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/parsing-docx-to-change-style-of-individual-words-t435.html
http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/how-to-set-text-color-t756.html